# A question about a function in the Lebesgue space $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I try to solve this exercise but it is difficult for me. Let $s\in L^{\frac{4}{3}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $t\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let $u$ the function such that
$$u(x)=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|s(x-y)|^{\frac{4}{3}}|t(y)|^2dy\right)^{\frac{1}{4}},\;x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
Why $u\in L^4(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

For $u\in L^4(\mathbb{R}^4)$, $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ will be measurable and $\lVert u \rVert_{L^4}<+\infty$. Why $u$ is measurable? Thank you so much.

I corrected the post.

Comment: It seems that $u = |s^{\frac 43}  * t^2|$ where $*$ indicates convolution. Does your situation then fall under the [Young's convolution inequality?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality)

Comment: You're right! I had not thought of it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: But, for use to the  Young's convolution inequality you need that $u=|t^2\ast s^{\frac{4}{3}}|$. Is correct?

Comment: It is correct, see the definition of $u$, it is exactly that.

Comment: Is it true that $|t^2\ast s^{\frac{4}{3}}|=|t|^2\ast |s|^{\frac{4}{3}}$? I calculated that $u^4=|t|^2\ast |s|^{\frac{4}{3}}$. Can I conclude that $u\in L^4(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: that is not really true, but for the purposes of bounding the norm, the second one will work